# print the 3rd item in a array

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, fetch

In my swift code I am attempting I would like to print the 3rd item in the array that was fetched from core data attribute atBATS. There is a sort descriptor in the code as well. Right now the code prints all the names just print the 3rd name. Assume that the array has 3 items in it.

```
 func printStrings() {
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)



            var retrievedData = [String]()

            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                
                let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "atBATS", ascending: false)
                 request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
                
                
                if let value = data.value(forKey: "atBATS") as? String {
                    retrievedData.append((value))


                }

            }


            print(retrievedData)


        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you just wanting print(retrievedData[2])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not name a custom struct or class `Data`. It can interfere with Foundation `Data`.

The sort descriptor is at the wrong place. It must be attached to the fetch request **before** fetching the data.

And you code is outdated. Use always the subclass of `NSManagedObject`. In the code below I name the class `MyData`

```
func printStrings() {
    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request : NSFetchRequest<MyData> = MyData.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "atBATS", ascending: false)]

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        let atBATS = result.map(\.atBATS)
        if atBATS.count > 2 {
            print(atBATS[2])
        } else {
            print("There are less than 3 items")
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```